# jasperserver strictly requires session affinity which is not possible in Microsoft Azure Load Balanced Virtual Machines

Tags: apache, azure, cluster-computing, load-balancing, jasperserver

I have deployed jasperserver with my web application in the environment like **Clustered two Tomcat sharing same database in Microsoft Azure Load Balanced Virtual Machines**. But the problem is jasperserver strictly requires session affinity which is not possible in Microsoft Azure Load Balanced Virtual Machines.

1) If you have any other solution/suggestion which is suitable for my environment, please guide me.

2) Which one is best suitable for my environment and why ? on comparing Azure load balanced Virtual Machines and Apache httpd load balancing.

**Environment :**
 1) Jasperserver 5.5 Commercial edition with session replication. 
 2) Two apache-tomcat-6.0.36 clustered instance sharing same database (Mysql 5.5). 
 3) Linux Machine - Ubuntu 13.10 Server in Azure load balanced Virtual Machines.

Thanks in advance for reading and answering my question. Every comment/idea is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at publishing a VM using the new (in preview) reserved public IP which avoids the cloud service / load balancing setup.  This VM could run your own custom load balancing setup that would allow session affinity (Kemp also offer their load balancer in azure - http://kemptechnologies.com/au/solutions/loadmaster-azure).  You could create a couple of these VMs and then use Azure Traffic Manager to front-end the setup.

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks for your suggestion and I need some analysis/googling and get back to you soon...because I am not have experience in the networking side, so if you gave me detailed explanation, It'll be really helpful.

Comment: Hi, Thanks Simon, I have configured with Kemp and it is working fine. But only one option (Source IP - Session Persistence) in the session persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell what are the steps needs to be follow for Kemp Load balancer which replaces Azure load balancing.   Thanks, Vasanth N

Comment: Hi Vasanth, Follow the steps in the link : http://kemptechnologies.com/files/downloads/documentation/7.0/Feature_Description/Feature_Description-LoadMaster_for_Azure.pdf.